# Vim Ack opens first file in current buffer

Tags: vim, ack

When i use Ack in vim (eg. :Ack `"INSERT INTO"`) it opens the first file with a result in the current buffer.
Is there a way to disable this, so I can browse the results before I open the file?

I'm using gVim 7.4 and follow this Ack Repository: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:Ack! xxxxxx xxx
```

you need the `[!]`

Comment: See `:h :Ack` for help